# Canonical transformation of the harmonic oscillator‘s Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I could deduce the Hamiltonian of the damped harmonic oscillator:

$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2m}e^{-2 \gamma t}+\frac{m \omega_0^2 q^2}{2}e^{2 \gamma t}
$$

Using the canonical transformation $Q=e^{\gamma t}q, P=e^{-\gamma t}p$ the Hamiltonian turns into:

$$
\bar{H}=\frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{m \omega_0^2Q^2}{2}
$$

The equations of motion follow from $\partial_Q H=-\dot{P}, \partial_PH=\dot{Q}$:

$$
m\omega_0^2Q=-\dot{P} \ \wedge \ \frac{P}{m}=\dot{Q} \Rightarrow \omega_0^2Q=-\ddot{Q}
$$

But I was apparently supposed to get: $\ddot{Q}+(\omega_0^2+\gamma^2)Q=0$, so what went wrong? Is maybe differentiation w.r.t. time not defined as I assumed?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry

Comment: This question should not have been closed - it asks a precise question with a well defined answer

Comment: @lux This is a check-my-work question, and the OP is asking the community to find an error somewhere.  As such it is almost the perfect prototype of question that *should* be closed.  *If* the OP can edit the question so as to highlight a conceptual problem then it should be rightly re-opened.

Comment: The OP *might* be interested by this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/590852/36194